# Fedora 35 web application with PHP and Apache server: "Failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I am working on a web application and the Apache server is in the directory /var/www/html. So I created a new folder named "web" to this project. I also created a .ini file on the directory /agrotermos/conf/conf.ini to initialize the environment variables. So, in this folder "web" I have a file with a function to connect to the database, and the first command is:

```
$variaveisdeambiente = parse_ini_file('/agrotermos/conf/conf.ini', true);
```

But when I open the index.html file on the browser, it gives me the following error:

> Warning: parse_ini_file(/agrotermos/conf/conf.ini): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/web/conndb.php on line 5

I tried to give a+rx permission to the hole "agrotermos" folder, but it didn't work. Then I changed the owner group of this folder from root to apache, but it didn't work as well. Any ideas of what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure all the "agrotermos" subdir and file have the same permissions and owner? Are you sure that Apache user is "apache" ( it should be on Fedora )

Comment: Yes! The "agrotermos" folder has this permissions:
drwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 16 Jun  2 15:35 conf
drwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache  0 Jun  2 14:11 log